# css/javascript for element positioning / sizing

Tags: javascript, css, dom, applet, element

I am after some general pointers on how to go about the following.

I am trying to position some elements (divs) in a web page by absolute position, relative to the element in which they live.

The idea being that the containing element top/left should be exactly where it would be in the normal document flow, the width should be set such that it fills `<body>` up to the RHS, less a small margin, and height such that it fills the remainder of the display window, less the space taken up by a footer (also a div).

Having done that, I can then absolutely position sub-elements inside it. The problem is setting the width/height of the containing element.

I have tried various combination of position properties and javascript executed onload(), without success. I clearly am not taking the right approach.

What I am really after are some pointers from someone who knows how to do this as to the approach to be taken. The bottom line is that I need that containing element to expand to be as big as it can, given the constraints of the browser window and the space taken by the footer element.

.... More info following comments.

Basically, I am trying to display a schedule, not unlike a TV/radio schedule. I.e. a line per event class, then within each line lots of individual events displayed in boxes, with the 'box width/position' scaled to the start/end of the actual event on a timeline.

I've seen this done simply using HTML tables and lots of columns to get
 the necessary granularity, then using colspan to vary the widths. However I thought I'd try to do it with absolute positioning of elements. The first problem being that the containing element then has no idea how big this thing is, because using position:absolute takes each element out of the document flow. Therefore, no scroll bars either, even with overflow-x:auto on the containing element.

I am getting nowhere fast with css/javascript (well, certainly nowhere, but not even very fast, actually), and I am starting to wonder of the only real way to control the UI closely is by writing a java applet to contain it all?

Hence my question: conceptually, what would be a good way of going about this?

Comment: Hi, You need to share your working code to give a better idea of your situation.

Comment: By positioning the elements absolutely, you are taking them out of the normal flow which defines the height of a containing element. You'll have to find some workaround to define the height of the container correctly.

Comment: I cannot provide code - haven't got anything that is even close to working yet. Conceptually I'm notr sure how to go about it, and that is the main problem. Yes, I understand the 'taking it out of the flow' issue - that is also part of the problem. I am adding some further comments to the above.

Answer (score 0):

for the container to contain an absolute element, the height must be set to a fixed height or dynamically set the height using Javascript.

See Example https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/kkWJaL

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s21.postimg.org/c1m6ky7dz/kingston_creative_market_cover_small_f.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container > img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Javascript with jQuery

```
window.onload = function() {
  var imgHeight = $('.container img').height();
  var targetHeight = imgHeight * 1.2;
  $('.container').height(targetHeight);
};
```